# R lme4 nested fixed effects. Do I nest as random effects?

Tags: r, lme4

I am currently fitting model in glmer (although the same question applies to lmer).

However I have two (what I think are) nested fixed effects. I am testing how long people spend eating compared to their sex and weight. Obviously how heavy someone is depends on their sex (the distribution of weights is different between the sexes), but I care about this in my model.  I want to test whether the heaviest women eats more than the lightest women and the heaviest man eats more than the lightest man, but I want one model to see if there is a population wide effect.

This is how I thought of doing it by having the two fixed effects also as nested random effect:

```
model <- glmer(TimeEating ~ Sex + Weight + (1|Sex:Weight), 
      data, family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

Comment: try `glm(TimeEating ~ Sex*Weight, data, family=poisson)`.  From what you've said here, there's no reason to use mixed models.  This might be more appropriate on CrossValidated, as it seems to be more of a statistical question and less of a programming question ...  Also, a Poisson response seems a bit for a measured time eating -- why would the time eating be a discrete, unitless count??

Comment: If you had repeat measurements on the same person, then you could add person ID as a random effect (`~ 1 | Person`).

Comment: Thanks guys. I was using Poisson as the model seemed to fit best. As the experiment was set up I have a lot of zeros! But having an experiment about what you said it seems to work, thanks. And yes I do have personID as a random, just didn't include it here!